# how to get value of a jquery cloned textbox?

Tags: jquery, textbox, get, clone

I'm creating a survey question that has multiple answers.

There is a `button` to clone the existing `textbox`.
however, how do I get the value of those cloned `textbox`, especially from the codebehind.

Here is my code:

```
 function generateRow() {
        if (totalans == 9) {
            $('#<%= label2.ClientID %>').html('<b>Maximum of 10 answers per questions reached</b>');
        }
        else {
            $("#ans").clone().prependTo("#ans2");
            totalans = totalans + 1;
        }
```

//#ans is a division.

Could anyone help me please.
I tried to get it.

//c# code behind

`String bla = tb_ans.ToString();
        String[] splitAnswer = bla.Split(',');
       int a = splitAnswer.Length;`

//tb_ans is my textbox id.

I tried to use an array, but it seems it only took the first `textbox` value while dumping the others.

Comment: You need to change the id of what you are cloning. 2 elements cannot share an id.

Comment: additional info : the button able to clone up to 8 times. therefor i dont think by assigning it to a specific id would be useful? no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After viewing your comment i've revised my answer:

```
function generateRow() {
    if (totalans == 9) {
        $('#<%= label2.ClientID %>').html('<b>Maximum of 10 answers per questions reached</b>');
    }
    else {
        totalans = totalans + 1; // same as totalans++;
         $("#ans").clone().attr({id: "ans_clone_" + totalans, name: "ans_clone_" + totalans}).prependTo("#ans2");
         // then you can loop through each input using the totalans variable.
    }
```

Comment: yeah thanks. but it will be able to clone 8 times.
does that mean I have to write 8 lines of that?

Comment: I changed my answer to include your totalans variable. you can loop through each input then.

Comment: thank you for the solution. however, im confused on how to get the value on the code behind now?

Comment: Are you using an aspx page to process the content? Or jQuery?
Basically you'll want to loop through something like this:
`for(x=0; x<totalans; x++){
 var tVal = $('#ans_clone_' + x).val();
 //process
}`

Comment: yeah im using aspx page c# to process the content. i will try to think of ways to get the value of the ans_clone inside html page from the .aspx.cs
thank you very much! :)

Comment: looks like Im still in need of help.
research n tried few ways but it seems that i cant figure out how to take the ans_clone_3 n so on.. could you kindly please assist me in this.

Comment: in the same page, i would need to store all the cloned textbox value to be inserted into the database. therefor i need it to code from behind to insert into db and get the value.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "code from behind". I don't know a lot about aspx and c# to instruct you on how to process the form data but I do know you could open a question stating you have a form with multiple inputs named "ans_clone_1", ...2,....3 and so on. 
I'm sure someone on stack-overflow would know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here that pop up right away:

Option one: instead of a clone, generate serverside and then hide until needed - change the display to show them when you need them.

Option two: send the values of the text box clones to the server via ajax.

Personally, I would opt for the second as that way you could have a virtually unlimited number of boxes cloned and then send the values to the server to handle - which, from your code you are part way there.

Comment: could you explain further on the option 2. i would prefer sending the value to the server as I am used to do to code behind.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit any form the element values are posted as per there name in the dom so when you clone textbox you should change there name and give a unique name if you want all the textboxes value in the server side.

Comment: hmm.. i dont quite understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a unique ID on the clone so you can then access it via javascript.  If you also want it to be submitted uniquely to your server as part of a form, then set a unique name on it too.

```
$("#ans").clone().attr({id: "ansClone2", name: "ansClone2"}).prependTo("#ans2");
```